# How to get the marker’s id when it is pressed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am using flutter. I want to get the clicked marker id when a marker is clicked on Google Maps. Or I would like to know if I clicked a marker or a map area. How can I do it?

I want to retrieve the ids dynamically and i have not been able to